# What are synonyms for "срач"?

Tags: лексикон, синонимы

I need to translate the word "срач" to a different language. I am having a hard time trying to say it in different words in order to accurately explain the exact shade of the meaning. Could you please propose some synonyms for "срач" to help me understand its meaning.

Comment: No guys, the question is fine, it asks not for a translation, but for other synonyms.

Comment: This word is very polysemic. Please clarify the meaning you are looking for, best by providing usage examples.

Comment: I forgot what I asked about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Synonyms for `срач` meaning "a mess":

- беспорядок
- грязь (в доме)
- бардак
- раскардаш
- свинюшник
- бедлам
- разгром

Comment: для меня запустение противоположно срачу. Можно устроить срач, а можно - запустение )))

Comment: @Dima Я думаю, имелась в виду "запущенность", не "запустение".

Comment: @Denis: согласен, запустение звучит странно.  Убрал.

Comment: Что такое раскардаш? Это кавардак или что?

Comment: @Anixx, Ну да. Беспорядок.

Answer (score 15):

Besides the common meaning of "mess", it can also mean "a quarrel", "a pointless argument", usually applied to discussions on the Internet. So, the synonyms for this meaning will be:

- ссора
- спор
- ругань

Usages are:

- "хохлосрач" — "a quarrel about Ukraine or Ukrainians"
- "срач на тему *чего-либо*" — "a quarrel about *something*"
- "развели тут срач!" — "you started a pointless argument"

And you may want to know about a verb "сраться" which means "to quarrel" and has synonyms:

- ссориться
- ругаться
- спорить

Usages:

- "Хватит сраться!", "Не сритесь!" — "Stop fighting!"

Comment: The English analogue would be "flamewar" though it's less rude that срач.

Answer (score 7):

The word "срач" has a strong negative, condescending connotation.

"Ну и срач у тебя дома" sounds similar to "Your home is a pigsty" and "У тебя дом весь загажен".

Similar, although milder, expressions are as follows: "У тебя дома бардак" (milder, but still condescending), "У тебя дома грязь, беспорядок" (neutral, non-judgmental).

Comment: Can also be "intense wrange involving obscene language."

Comment: the question was specifically about synonyms, maybe you could add some to your answer?

Answer (score 7):

Everyone forgot such a wonderful word as holywar or flaming :) срач is a usual business at Internet forums, there disputing on some matter in offensive and warring manner easily become a holywar, there noone wants to agree or to understand position of another person.

If thread in forum have already started with provocational topic, oftenly someone may post an ironical disclaimer in English LET THE SRATCH BEGIN!

Answer (score 4):

Also is possible to use:

- кавардак
- гадюшник

Answer (score 1):

If you witness people arguing in comments(on the Web) it's also may be considered as срач. the synonym would be "butthurt".
in other situations(if they refer to something physical) the euphemism  would be "a mess".